# How do i connect my server-client automatically using c# windows forms

Tags: c#, sockets, connection, client-server

I've done the server-client connection, but now my goal is to make the connection automatically ...
Can someone give me tips on how to do it?

Initially I made the connection with buttons, to create the server and for the connection of the client to the server

The code is here for questions:

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());      //Vai buscar o IP do computador

                foreach(IPAddress address in localIP)
                    {
                    if(address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) // se o Ip corresponder com o IPv4 vai aparecer na txtbox o ip da maquina
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = address.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Criar o server
            {
                TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,int.Parse( textBox4.Text)); // permite que a pass seja uma qualquer em numeros apenas
                Listener.Start();   
                client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                STW.AutoFlush = true; //buffering ilimitados. 
                                      //Quando AutoFlush é definido como false, StreamWriter fará uma quantidade limitada de buffering

                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); // Começar a receber dados em segundo plano
                backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; // Capacidade de cancelar o ligacao



            }

            private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) // Receber dados
            {
                while(client.Connected) //enquanto o cliente tiver conectado vai ler o que servidor diz em chat 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        receive = STR.ReadLine();
                        this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { textBox2.AppendText("server: " + receive + "\n"); }));
                        receive = "";
                     }
                    catch(Exception x)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) // enviar dados
            {
                if(client.Connected) //enquanto o cliente tiver conectado pode escrever para o servidor
                {
                    STW.WriteLine(text_to_send);
                    this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { textBox2.AppendText("cliente: " + text_to_send + "\n"); }));
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Envio Falhado!");
                }

            }

            private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //conectar ao servidor
            {
                client = new TcpClient();
                IPEndPoint IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox5.Text), int.Parse(textBox6.Text)); // sincronizacao do IP com a porta
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(IP_End);
                    if(client.Connected)
                    {
                        textBox2.AppendText("Conectado ao servidor" + "\n");
                        STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                        STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                        STW.AutoFlush = true;

                        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); // Começar a receber dados em background
                        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; // possibilidade de cancelar o fio

                    }
                }catch(Exception x)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // botao de envio
            {
                if(text_to_send != "")
                {
                    text_to_send = textBox1.Text;
                    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered SignalR?

Comment: no! I do not know how to use it, I'm a beginner in this field.